# Has any (additional) debris from Mir de-orbiting been found?

Tags: reentry, debris, mir

After reading the answers from [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13303) question and reading the excellent article [here](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/mir_2001.html) that goes through the de-orbiting in detail, I wondered if any debris had been found after it plunged into the ocean?

I was skeptical when I read [this](http://boston.cbslocal.com/2013/06/14/rock-found-in-amesbury-backyard-came-from-space-station/) CBS News report of a person in Massachusetts, USA finding a piece of Mir. (How did it get there?) Most of the other Google results are about debris in orbit.

Now, the ocean is probably pretty deep where Mir came down and it is ~1,100 miles from the coast of New Zealand, so perhaps it is not very likely.

Has any other debris been found?

Comment: Taco Bell is conspiring to hide any evidence, lest there be a claim on a free Taco to every for hitting their banner.  Never underestimate the power of a motivated fast food vendor!